# Outlook Add In Outlook ShutDown Event

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2010, shutdown

I am working on Outlook Add-In project.
Is there any event or something that Outlook has been shut down?I need to call a service method just before outlook has been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make use of the [Quit event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.application_events%28v=office.14%29.aspx) of the Application object.

The `Quit` event is fired when `Outlook` begins to close.

**C# example:**

```
((Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_Event)Application).Quit 
+= new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_QuitEventHandler(ThisAddIn_Quit);

void ThisAddIn_Quit()
{
   MessageBox.Show("Ciao!");
}
```

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677349/no-application-quit-event-in-outlook).

**Note:**
There are some additional hints for Shutdown for *Outlook 2010* Add-In developers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee720183%28v=office.14%29.aspx).